# Syntax error on token "1", Identifier expected in Enum Java

Tags: java-8

I want to implement `Enum` for `Number`, I want to get its respective String values. I already followed link: http://www.makeinjava.com/convert-enum-integer-string-value-java/.

The error which I'm getting is

> Syntax error on token "1", Identifier expected
>
> Syntax error on token "2", Identifier expected

```
public enum CompanyCityType {
    1("New York"),
    2("Reston");
    
    private Integer companyCityType;

    CompanyCityType(Integer companyCityType) {
        this.companyCityType = companyCityType;
    }

    public Integer getCompanyAddrType() {
        return this.companyCityType;
    }
}
```

Comment: there is not that much advantage in creating an enum called `1 ` instead of just using `1`; maybe `NEW_YORK` or so (a type name probably would be better) would be a lot more informative

Comment: You can't name a field starting with a number, thats the rule in Java.

Comment: Enum Constants are [3.8. Identifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8): *"An identifier is an unlimited-length sequence of Java letters and Java digits, the first of which must be a Java letter."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot begin any identifier name in Java with a number, it must follow the rules as specified for having a valid variable name in Java.

As per the Oracle variable [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html):

> Variable names are case-sensitive. A variable's name can be any legal
>   identifier — an unlimited-length sequence of Unicode letters and
>   digits, beginning with a letter, the dollar sign "$", or the
>   underscore character "_".

As the fields in an `enum` are actually `public static final fields` (singleton instances) or ***class variables*** they follow the same set of naming rules as a normal Java variable.

You need to refactor your code to:

```
public enum CompanyCityType {

    NEW_YORK(1),
    RESTON(2);

    private int companyCityType;

    CompanyCityType(int companyCityType) {
        this.companyCityType = companyCityType;
    }

    public int getCompanyAddrType() {
        return this.companyCityType;
    }
}
```